# Highlighting Text When a Part is Selected in the Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Currently, I have successfully been able to isolate and highlight parts or assemblies in the autodesk-forge viewer, with external buttons. When a button is pressed externally, it will automatically zoom into the selected part inside the viewer. It is explained more  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62345225/controlling-the-autodesk-forge-viewer-with-external-buttons). My next step now, is to have those external parts on the website, highlight when a part is clicked inside the viewer. How can I have a function be executed (a highlight text function) when the user selects a part on the viewer. I have tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```
if (viewer.isolate(dbId) == true){
highlightFunction()
}
```

Any help on how a function can be executed when a user selects a part on the viewer would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then all you need to do is listen to the selection event and call your function from there:

```
viewer.addEventListener(
  Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, 
  (event) => { // do what you need }
)
```

Here is a sample: [Selection override](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/selection-override)

If you're working with multiple models in the **Viewer** then listen to the **AGGREGATE_SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT** event instead. See [Multi-model refresher](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/multi-model-refresher)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Adam Nagy. That helps a lot!

Comment: But what type of events can i put. For example, can i use viewer.isolate(dbid) inside the event?

Comment: Yes, you can use isolate() inside the event handler

Comment: How can i fire a function every time a part is isolated I tried the following but it does not work: function eventCheck(){
    viewer.addEventListener(
        Autodesk.Viewing.ISOLATE_EVENT, 
        (event) => {  console.log('part isolated'); }
      )
    }                                                                                     Thanks again fro your help @Adam Nagy

Comment: EDIT from last comment:  Nevermind it works now, however how can I grab a property name value when I select a part, thanks again @Adam Nagy

Comment: You can get the properties of the selected object using viewer.getProperties() as shown e.g. here https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/property-inspector-viewer